# MY xbox 360-ps3 controller is not working. But my ps4 controller is working

Tags: kubuntu, 21.04

I'm using xboxdrv. it starts well but can't find any input.

```
xboxdrv 0.8.8 - http://pingus.seul.org/~grumbel/xboxdrv/ 
Copyright © 2008-2011 Ingo Ruhnke <grumbel@gmail.com> 
Licensed under GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html> 
This program comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY. 
This is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions; see the file COPYING for details. 

Controller:        Microsoft X-Box 360 pad
Vendor/Product:    045e:028e
USB Path:          001:005
Controller Type:   Xbox360

Your Xbox/Xbox360 controller should now be available as:
  /dev/input/js0
  /dev/input/event21

Press Ctrl-C to quit, use '--silent' to suppress the event output
```

Kubuntu 21.04

Comment: I would just use 20.04.  It is a LTS so it will generally have fewer bugs and better support.  Kubuntu 20.04 will be supported for 3 years. 20.10 is already EOL.  Consider filing a bug report for 21.04. Devs can't fix problems they don't know about and the more reports from different users, the higher priority a bug will get.

Comment: 21.04 will be supported for more than three years. I am using 21.04

Comment: No, it won't.  21.04 will be EOL in January 2022.  It is a standard release and will only have 9 months of support. See: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases

Comment: Okay, but still, this is irrelevant.

Comment: How is it irrelevant? You said the problem doesn't exist using 20.04 LTS. If you want to solve the problem, one solution is to use 20.04 LTS.

Comment: 21.04 is a base for 21.10 and newer versions. So I think that it should be fixed. Note: I'm using **K**ubuntu 21.04.

Comment: Have you [filed a bug report](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug) yet?  If you want this fixed, you should file a bug report.  In the meantime, you have a solution available to you.  We do not accept bug reports on Ask Ubuntu.  Bugs reported here do not get entered into the bug tracking system.

Comment: Okay, I'll do it asap.

Comment: I've updated some stuff. Now my PS4 controller seems to work. My XBOX 360 controller is detected but not giving any input.